# setting POI XWPFParagraph line spacing

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

i want to set line spacing on all paragraph in my document created using POI library. 
i want to set the paragraph line spacing to 1.0, and remove space before and after paragraph, but the generated document keep using 1.15 line spacing and add space after paragraph.
this is my code:

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()) {
        paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
        paragraph.setSpacingAfterLines(0);
        paragraph.setSpacingBefore(0);
        paragraph.setSpacingBeforeLines(0);
        paragraph.setSpacingLineRule(LineSpacingRule.EXACT);
        paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);
    }
```

please help,
Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can use following code set paragraph line spacing to Single:

```
public void setSingleLineSpacing(XWPFParagraph para) {
    CTPPr ppr = para.getCTP().getPPr();
    if (ppr == null) ppr = para.getCTP().addNewPPr();
    CTSpacing spacing = ppr.isSetSpacing()? ppr.getSpacing() : ppr.addNewSpacing();
    spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.AUTO);
    spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(240));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1);
```

It will create a spacing of 1 between lines of paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Also that is an other alternative solution 
To use it ; you have to add ooxml-schemas dependency in your pom.xml

```
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
        pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(7200L));
```